# Como criar formulário editável usando "Popover"

Tags: angularjs

Como devo modificar o código abaixo para que funcione com a classe `popover-wrapper` do Angular-xeditable → [Demo](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-popover).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"])
.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
})
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.targetIndex = -1;
  
  $scope.toggle = function(index){

    // Se o targetIndex atual for o mesmo do selecionado, então apague.
    // Caso contrário, salve o índice selecionado em targetIndex.

    $scope.targetIndex = ($scope.targetIndex == index ? null : index);
  }
  
  $scope.users = [
  {    name: 'awesome user I'  }, 
  {    name: 'awesome user II'  }, 
  ];
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>

<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>

<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" editable-form name="formulario">
  
  <div ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
  <a href="#" ng-click="toggle($index)" ng-show="!(targetIndex == $index)" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
  <input type='text' ng-model="user.name" ng-show="targetIndex == $index"/>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="targetIndex == $index">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="toggle($index)">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="toggle($index)">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Deseja o efeito do exemplo ou manipular esse evento e exibir o seu próprio botão de cancelar e salvar?

Comment: Olá @FelipeDuarte, o do exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você adicionar mais duas dependências: `boostrap css` e o `xeditable css`, também removi o `form`, pois a `api` faz todo o trabalho dinamicamente.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"])
.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
})
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  //Comentei esse trecho pois ele estava ocultando o botão
 
  //$scope.targetIndex = -1;
  
  //$scope.toggle = function(index){

    // Se o targetIndex atual for o mesmo do selecionado, então apague.
    // Caso contrário, salve o índice selecionado em targetIndex.

    //$scope.targetIndex = ($scope.targetIndex == index ? null : index);
  //}
  
  $scope.users = [
  {    name: 'awesome user I'  }, 
  {    name: 'awesome user II'  }, 
  ];
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }
.pop {
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.popover-wrapper:active{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="user in users track by $index" class="pop">
  <div class="popover-wrapper">
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggle($index)" ng-show="!(targetIndex == $index)" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá @FelipeDuarte, não sei se percebeu, mas a estrutura está dentro de um `form`, o que impossibilita seu funcionamento padrão.

Comment: Opa, perdão, entendi que gostaria de reproduzir o exemplo da API, mas enfim, sua pergunta não está muito clara, seria legal reformula-la, para que todos entendessem melhor.

Comment: Felipe, não tem muito o que detalhar, quero que o meu exemplo (com form) fique "igual" ao **demo** (com popup).

Comment: ainda está por aí?

Comment: opa, pode falar

Comment: Poderia me ajudar com essa questão pelo chat? @FelipeDuarte

Comment: Esse horário é difícil para mim, mas sua questão é a seguinte, a API fornece todos os métodos necessários para manipular as requisições, tanto submit quanto cancel, então ela mesmo não permite o uso de formulários, até porque não teria muito sentido, você pode encontrar o método submit aqui https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#onbeforesave